4 byte binary integer resets above 128 (or its multiples)
I read binary data from an instrument but the output is quite weird. I have a python program that relies on pyvisa that I describe below. The weird thing is that everytime 128, or a multiple of 128, is crossed, the data exhibit a weird behaviour. I can fortunately compare the binary output with the integer output produced by the machine. The binary representation seems wrong (see below). Note that this present post is related to this post, where you would see how I ended up with this program to retrieve the data, but now I am facing a different problem.
Program
import pyvisa
from pyvisa.constants import StopBits, Parity
import struct

# Connect to instrument
# SR620 Universal Time Interval Counter
rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
TAC = rm.open_resource('ASRL4::INSTR',
                            baud_rate = 19200,
                            data_bits = 8,
                            stop_bits = StopBits(20),
                            parity    = Parity(0),
                            read_termination='\r\n')

# list where result is stored
meanlist = []
# retrieve histogram as binary
# 10 slices of 25 points
for j in range(0,10):
    data = TAC.query_binary_values("XHST? "+str(j)+";*WAI", datatype='i',
                    is_big_endian=False,
                    data_points=25,
                    header_fmt = 'empty', expect_termination = True)
    meanlist.extend(data)

# retrieve histogram as integer
meanlist_int = []
    for j in range(1,250):
        meanlist_int.append( int(float(TAC.query(f'HSPT? {j}') ) ))


Output example
I then plot meanlist (blue curve) and meanlist_int (orange curve) for comparison (using matplotlib.pyplot.step). Horizontal line is 128. This plot is only a focus on few data points for clarity.

binary check versus integer output
When checking the binary, I noticed that the data was expressed so the least-significant bit is expressed as an ascii character when the number is below 128, but then as four '\x00' style bytes for higher values.
So the binary output gives, for instance, 2 as \x02\x00\x00\x00, 112 as p\x00\x00\x00, 125 as }\x00\x00\x00, 127 as \x7f\x00\x00\x00 but surprisingly 128 as \x00\x00\x00\x00.
Is this a problem with the machine that produces this, or is this in the way I read or process the data ?

I know practically nothing about pyvisa, but just taking a wild swing at it,... What happens if you use datatype='I' (note the capital "I") instead?

Same thing, whether it is i, I, l or L.
